# Is it Possible to Change a Custom Post Type Permalink Structure to Use %post_id% instead of %postname%?

Tags: php, wordpress

For whatever reason, this seemingly simple task is causing some issues for me.

I have a custom post type with a permalink structure similar to this:

`http://mywebsite.com/projects/the-name-of-my-project/`

However, I want something like this:

`http://mywebsite.com/projects/52418/`

Were this a regular old post and not a custom post type, I would simply setup my permalink structure as:

`/projects/%post_id%/`

But because it's a custom post type, the method has eluded me.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, well, apparently there's a plugin for that: http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following page about `register_post_type`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Consider reading this segement: `permalink_epmask` and `rewrite`. This have enough code example.

I am not in the favour of installing plugin for a small task.